# Writing ActiveX control in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, activex

Currently I am trying to write some application inside an ActiveX control to use it in Excel, Word and Powerpoint. This should be done in C# and I would be totally happy with a single Label with Hello World text.

Using visual Studio 2013, I created an MFC ActiveX control (which draws an elipse). This works in Word, Excel and Powerpoint, but is C++ instead of C#.

So, here is what I tried:

- Created a new solution with a C# Library project.
- I set the "register for COM interop" flag in the settings
- I ran VS with admin rights to allow studio to register and unregister
- I wrote a class the derives from UserControl and creates a label (User control tested in application)
- I added

```
[ProgId("ActiveXHelloWorld.HelloWorld")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("some self created GUID")]
[ComVisible(true)]
```

and ensured that class name and namespace match the ProgID

- I signed the assembly with a self generated key
- I build the solution and checked, that the command is registered (regedit)
- The control is available in word, but when I tried to place it, I get

> The program used to create this object is {some self created GUID}. That program is either not installed on your computer or it is not responding. To edit this object, install {some self created GUID}or ensure that any dialog boxes in {some self created GUID}are closed.

Does anyone have a working minimal example or can explain to me what I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create ActiveX in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712815/how-to-create-activex-in-c-sharp)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step